# Maximum interval of existence and range of solution of ODE1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The given ODE is: $y'=(1-y^2)^{10}\cos(y),\ \ y(0) =0$

We need to obtain J= Maximum interval of existence and K= Range of solution of the problem.

I could estimate by the existence and uniqueness theorem of Picard, that J=[-1, 1]. How can I find K?
I am new to these problems.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The right side has roots at $\pm 1$ and any $\frac\pi2+k\pi$. Can any solution have poles, unbounded growth?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I would be grateful if you kindly elaborate the concept being used here. I am assuming you mean it should be bounded within [-1+1]?

Comment: Exactly. As such, the solution can not end at a finite time.